# Perl package defined in script file, how to have package export subroutines?

Tags: perl

Given the following:

```
package My::Pack;

use Exporter::Easy (
    OK => [ qw(pack_func) ],
);

sub pack_func {
    ...
}

package main;
<script here that uses pack_func>
```

How do I import the symbol I want?

`use` doesn't work since it's looking for another file to open.
`require` doesn't support the syntax that `use` does for specifying the symbols you want.

Are my only choices to say `My::Pac::pack_func()` in the script or import the symbol manually through typeglob assignmnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement:

```
use Some::Module qw(foo bar);
```

is [exactly equivalent to](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html):

```
BEGIN {
    require Some::Module;
    Some::Module->import( qw(foo bar) );
}
```

in your case, the code for the `My::Pack` module has already been loaded, so you don't need to `require` it.  Thus, you can just do:

```
BEGIN { My::Pack->import( qw(pack_func) ) }
```

Comment: Do you mean `BEGIN { My::Pack->import(qw(pack_func)) }`?

Comment: I had completely forgotten that Exporter et al run an import() sub that uses caller to figure out who wants the symbol in their namespace.  Thank you!